# Windows 8, Fedora 19 OS Hyper-V Virtual Machine

Tags: windows-8, fedora, hyper-v

I installed Fedora 19 in windows 8 hyper-v and its working fine but there is one small problem with the display setting, as fedora 19 display setting not providing 1366x768, but i need to set the display to 1366x768 to view full screen, so any suggestions??

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- Open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>)
- Run

  ```
    sudo vi /etc/default/grub
  ```
- Find the line starting with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX, and add

  ```
    video=hyperv_fb:[the resolution you want]
  ```

If the resolution I want is 1280×720 then my line ends up looking like this:

```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="… quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:1280×720"
```

- Write the changes and quit vi by hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd> and typing

  ```
    :wq
  ```
- Run:

  ```
    sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
  ```

  or when installed in EFI mode

  ```
    sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
  ```
- Reboot the virtual machine

Comment: Hi. I've tested this solution with Fedora 22 with success.

Comment: works with Fedora 23 too, except the variable name is GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX, and not GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT .

Comment: Worked perfectly for Fedora 24 on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: And for Fedora 25 on Windows 10 x64

Comment: Doesn't work for Fedora 26 on Windows 10 x64. FWIW, the `grub.cfg` didn't exist after fresh install. After reboot the `video=` option doesn't appear in `/proc/cmdline`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I know what happened.

Comment: it does work but the location of grub.cfg depends on whether os was installed in EFI mode or not. its either /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg or /boot/grub2/grub.cfg .

Comment: Thanks!. I added the path to the answer.

Comment: This worked for me with Fedora 33 on Windows 10 Hyper-V. I used video=hyperv_fb=1920x1080.

Answer (score 4):

(Note: this is just an over-sized reply.)

I'm using Windows 10 and Fedora 26. Basically what [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172319/windows-8-fedora-19-os-hyper-v-virtual-machine/28497106#28497106) said still holds, with some modifications:

1. The file `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` doesn't exist on fresh install Fedora 26, and creating the file doesn't affect booting parameters at all (verified with `/proc/cmdline`). The correct file is `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` (I get the path from [Fedora Wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2#Create_a_GRUB_2_configuration)).
2. Not every resolution is supported: 1920x1080 is, 2560x1080 is not. Unsupported resolution is simply ignored. I ended up setting it 1920 although my monitor is 2560.

And finally an advice: back up everything you edit. You'll need it some day.

Update: still works in Fedora 27.

Comment: Running Fedora 27 in Hyper-V on 10x64 1709, I cannot get anything other than 1024x768. Looking at /proc/cmdline, I can see it had the correct video parameter https://imgur.com/x8cYva8 (I'm like you, I have a 2560x1080 monitor, but gotta limit to 1920x1080)

Comment: @jparnell8839 Not sure whether it helps, but mine has `splash` before the `video` settings, similar to what Daniel has.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a limitation from Microsoft.

Here's the link http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/19f32070-46c7-4dec-8824-9942f7fc5a2c/hyperv-and-display-resolution?forum=winserverhyperv

Your only option is RDP.